# How not to use <Space> as a hit-enter key in command output pager

Tags: key-bindings

According to `:h hit-enter`, a message is shown when there is something on the screen to read and the screen is about to be redrawn. For example,

```
- After executing an external command (e.g., ":!ls" and "=").
- Something is displayed on the status line that is longer than the width of
  the window, or runs into the 'showcmd' or 'ruler' output.
```

When the `:h hit-enter` prompt is shown, the user can press `<Enter>` or `<Space>` to redraw the screen. The user can also press `:` or any other Normal mode command character to start that command.

Now,I have grown accustomed to a keybinding that lets me use `<Space>;` as `:`

```
nnoremap <Leader>; :
xnoremap <Leader>; :
```

I was hoping I could use `<Space>;` as `:` when the `:h hit-enter` message is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the mappings for the pager are hard-coded. See `wait_return()` in `message.c`:

```
/*
 * If the user hits ':', '?' or '/' we get a command line from the next
 * line.
 */
if (c == ':' || c == '?' || c == '/')
```